# Comparing floats in SQL, PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have the following SQL executing:

```
$query = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM active_notifications WHERE direction = ">"
AND trigger_price > "$floatUsdTrigger" ');
```

If I replace `$floatUsdTrigger` with a number, it works as expected; however it fails to work with my `$floatUsdTrigger` variable. This variable is a `float` cast as a `string`, and when I do a `vardump` it looks correct e.g `(float) 120.00`.

My `trigger_price` is a `varchar[10]`, and like I said is fine when I replace the `$floatUsdTrigger` with a number; any ideas?

I did a good amount of research and couldn't find an answer to this; as an objective C developer, I find PHP to be infuriatingly "loose" at times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `->prepare`, *please* don't use variable interpolation with this!

Do it like this:

```
$query = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM active_notifications WHERE direction = ">" AND trigger_price > ?');
$query->execute(array($floatUsdTrigger));

while($row = $query->fetch()){
    // var_dump($row);
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the input, appreciated as always.

Answer (score 3):

The $floatUsdTrigger var isn't parsed inside single quotes.  You would see this if you echo out that string.

Suggestion: use double quotes for the entire string and use single quotes around text values that are part of the query.